# FAST way to sum up neighbors' attributes in a large graph in R

Tags: r, igraph, sna, large-data

I have a large igraph object with almost a 1M nodes and 1.5M edges. After researching a while I could not find a procedure to sum a node's neighbors attributes, in this case, it's a binary one. At the moment, the best solution I found way the following:

```
V(g)$sum = sapply( ego(g,1,V(g),mode = 'all',mindist = 1), function(v) sum(V(G)[v]$attr) )
```

However, after 12 hours it's still crunching.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1:** Let's consider the following graph

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph.formula(1-+2,1-+3,2-+4,2-+5,3-+6,5-+7,7-+8,8-+9,9+-7, 9-+10,
               6-+9,1-+5,3-+9,10-+11,11-+12,11-+5,12-+4,4-+10,10-+4,11-+10)
V(G)$attr = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
plot(G, vertex.label.color = "white",  edge.width=E(G)$weight, layout = layout.circle(G))
```

[image]

and the desired outcome should be this...

```
 sapply( ego(G,1,V(G),mode = 'all',mindist = 1), function(v) sum(V(G)[v]$attr) )
 [1] 2 2 2 1 4 1 2 2 1 2 1 1
```

@Tamás, I tried to access the neighbors function without using a loop, but instead of the outcome described above I got this...

```
sapply(neighbors(G,V(G)),function (v) sum(V(G)[v]$attr))
2 3 5 
1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also working with large networks and I'm having some problems with the time it takes `igraph` to do "simple" stuff, like calculating `betweenness` and `closeness`. In your case, however, I think you can work around this issue outside the network framework.

1st, convert your network into a `data.frame` and use the library `data.table`, which is really fast for working large data sets to calculate the sum of the attributes.

```
library(igraph)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

# simple network
  g<- graph.formula(1-+2,1-+3,2-+4,2-+5,3-+6,5-+7,7-+8,8-+9,9+-7, 9-+10,
                     6-+9,1-+5,3-+9,10-+11,11-+12,11-+5,12-+4,4-+10,10-+4,11-+10)

  V(g)$attr = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)


# convert the network to data.table
  dt <- as_long_data_frame(g) %>% setDT()

# Calculate the sum of neighbors' attributes by origin (from). This is really fast in data.table
  mysum <- dt[, .(attr_sum = sum(to_attr)), by= from]

# get the sum result back in the data doing a simple merge
  dt <- dt[mysum, on=.(from)] 

# get the sum into the network object
  E(g)$attr_sum <- dt$attr_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is almost surely the `ego()` function. Try using `neighbors()` instead; it is specialized to get the first-order neighbors only so it is faster - and you don't need to construct V(g) in every iteration either.

Comment: I use this command sapply(V(G), function(v) sum(neighbors(G, v, mode = 'all')$attr)), but there is not significant improvement

Comment: Try pre-fetching the attribute for all vertices into a variable (e.g., `attr <- V(g)$attr`) and then subsetting that variable (i.e. `attr[neighbors(G, v, mode="all")]`). Not sure if this helps, though.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Tamás, the bottleneck lies in the `ego` function (`neighbors` will create a similar bottleneck). For adjacent nodes (i.e., neighbors of order 1), this bottleneck can be avoided by pulling the adjacency matrix using `get.adjacency` and then multiplying the matrix by the attribute vector using `%*%`:

```
library(igraph)    
set.seed(42)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000000, 1500000, type = "gnm")
V(g)$att <- as.logical(rbinom(vcount(g), 1, 0.5))

system.time({
   ma  <- get.adjacency(g)
   att <- V(g)$att
   res <- as.numeric(ma %*% att)
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.642   0.138   0.786
```